# Colored blocks for numbered theorems in beamer

Tags: beamer, numbering, color, theorems, block

**Input:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] 

\begin{document}

\section{First section} 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Theorems} 
\begin{definition} 
    Text 
\end{definition} 
\begin{theorem} 
    Text
\end{theorem} 
\begin{lemma} 
    Text
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem} 
    Text
\end{theorem} 
\begin{example} 
    Text
\end{example} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Question:** Note that example's blocks are green and all other blocks are blue. How to define a specific color for each kind of block? For example, red for theorems and yellow for definitions. **It is important to keep the automatic consecutive numbering.**

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark to help reduce the number of unanswered questions.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou Accepted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need to put in your preamble

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% new package to be loaded
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{% set of commands to be added
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=orange}% colors to change
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=yellow}% colors to change
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=green,bg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=purple}

}
```

### Complete MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered] 
\AtBeginEnvironment{theorem}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=orange}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=yellow}
}
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=green,bg=red}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black,bg=purple}
}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black} 

\begin{document}

\section{First section} 
\begin{frame} 
\frametitle{Theorems}
\begin{proof} 
    Text 
\end{proof} 
\begin{definition} 
    Text 
\end{definition} 
\begin{theorem} 
    Text
\end{theorem} 
\begin{lemma} 
    Text
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem} 
    Text
\end{theorem} 
\begin{example} 
    Text
\end{example} 
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I found one more problem. The particular block `\begin{proof} Text \end{proof}` has a automatic blue square inside the text area. The given code `\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}...` changes the color of the block but doesn't affect the square's color. Is it possible to change the color of that square?

Comment: @Pedro Modify `\setbeamercolor{qed symbol}{fg=orange}`, or whatever you like.

Comment: @Pedro it worked without problems. Check my update.